# Can I declare a variable to a same variable?

Tags: vb.net

Does this work:

```
Dim Y As Integer
Y = Y + 1
```

Or is it gonna be an error?
The code I am trying is :

```
Dim X, Y As Integer
X = 6
y = y + 1
If Y > X Then X = X + 1
msgbox(Y)
```

Comment: Are you coding in notepad? Please try it yourself to see and learn what happens.

Comment: No, I am using Visual Basic but right now I am on a different device and I dont have it.

Comment: Here is what I am checking about : `Dim X,Y as integer` `X=6` `y=y+1` `if y>x then x=x+1` `msgbox(y)`

Comment: I tried it and I got the answer as "1" but I am not comfortable with it

Comment: OK mate, edit your post and add the code to check it.

Comment: I am new, so I will be sorry for the mess that I am doing.

Comment: Thanks bro for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is valid. You're setting the value of `Y` equal to itself plus 1. There is also the `+=` operand that does the same exact thing:

```
Dim Y As Integer = 0
Y += 1 ' Y now equals 1
```

Example: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pkjuOk)

Comment: Thanks bro for your help

Comment: @iiSwift_ It is worth noting that if you do not assign an Integer variable a value, it is assigned a default value of `0` behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I thought the answer was an error.

Comment: I was like, how can Y be equal to Y

Comment: @iiSwift_ The equals sign in `Y = Y +1` is an assignment operator. The expression on the right is being assigned to the variable on the left. Not like algebra where it signals equality. In an `If` statement `If x = y Then` it is a comparison operator and will return True or False to the If.